# Count number of spaces ' ' in N pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

Is there a way how to count number of spaces ' ' (some UIFont) in N pixels?

For example:

```
input: length = 100 pixels, font =  <fontName>

output: 14 spaces with current font
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the width of a space then see how many times that fits in the length you have.

```
NSInteger length = 100; // size in points (not pixels)
UIFont *font = ... // some font

CGSize spaceSize = [@" " sizeWithAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }]; // size in points (not pixels)

NSInteger spaceCount = floor(length / spaceSize.width);
```

This calculates the number of whole spaces that will fit in the allotted length.

Note that all of the code works in points, not pixels. if you really want to know how many spaces fits in screen pixels, you will need to account for the screen scale.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *oneSpace = @" ";
CGSize fontSize = [oneSpace sizeWithAttributes: @{
   NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12 ]}];

return floor(100 / fontSize.width);
```

Comment: FYI - `' '` is not an `NSString`.